# How to use MButil/patch with Python?

Tags: python, mbutil

I am very new to all this coding/scripting thing and now don't know how to use https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil/blob/master/patch. It just says

`$ patch [source] [dest]`

but where do I put this? Python, I guess, but it says that the syntax is invalid when I put

`patch C:/Temp/1.mbtiles C:/Temp/2.mbtiles`

Or do I have to use another command interpreter? Execute it from a certain folder?

Answer (score 1):

The script that you are referring to is a Bash shell script and not a Python script. Therefore you need to make sure to run it in a Bash shell. How to do this has been discussed on SO before (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413377/is-there-a-way-to-run-bash-scripts-on-windows)). You could install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys), and it would probably work. However, if you just need to run this simple script (and not too often), this would be rather overkill in my opinion.

Alternatively, you might simply want to run the commands from the script manually in SQLite using SQL (e.g. with [sqlite3 command line tool](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) or probably even a GUI interface such as [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org) might work). All the SQL commands are written at the bottom in the [script](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil/blob/master/patch), lines 31 to 36:

```
PRAGMA journal_mode=PERSIST;
PRAGMA page_size=80000;
PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;
ATTACH DATABASE '$1' AS source;
REPLACE INTO map SELECT * FROM source.map;
REPLACE INTO images SELECT * FROM source.images;
```

You need to do this with your destination database open, and `$1` is the path to your source database. Not very elegant, but should work.